# publishing similar apps on apple store

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program, apple-store

I am an indiviual developer (I also have a company too).

Some of our clients want to publish apps that can support their business. We have created a template app for one of the customers, and for others I have had the idea to change the look, appearance and a few bit features for each and publish them on the App Store.

The problem is, will Apple allow to publish similar apps? If not how can I do that?

Comment: Ask Different is not the place to ask developer questions. Perhaps you would like to post your question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @duci9y I disagree. SO is for programming issues, and there is none in my opinion here. The OP wants to know more about the Apple ecosystem, which fits perfectly here I believe.

Comment: But the question is about the Developer Program, and information about that is under NDA. But yeah, it doesn’t belong on SO, it belongs on the Developer Forums at Apple.

Comment: Hi there, what happened to this? Did you manage to pass the apple's strict review process for your similar looking apps ?